# Sending custom data to Google Tag Manager Server Side container

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I have just configured a server side instance of Google Tag Manager for a site and have successfully routed all Analytics data through from the client container.

My question is regarding the best method for sending data to be consumed by a custom client? For example let's say I have a client on server side that watches for requests made to `/collect/lead` and expects this to have properties `foo` and `bar` which
are defined from 1st Party Cookies on client side.

My current implementation is using Custom HTML tags on the client side to send a request to endpoint with Iframes.

```
<iframe src="https://gtm.mydomain.com/collect/lead?foo={{Cookie_Foo}}&bar={{Cookie_Bar}}" height="1" width="1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

What would be a better way of sending requests from GTM Client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created custom Data Client ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/gtm-server/data-client)) for GTM Server Side and Data tag ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/gtm-server/data-tag)) for GTM Web container. You can use a Data tag to send info from the Web to the Server.

Also, you can check out my detailed [How to send data from Google Tag Manager Web Container to Server Container](https://stape.io/sending-data-from-google-tag-manager-web-container-to-the-server-container/)